# Need Raw XML For Request & Response In UPS API (.Net console app)

Tags: api, soap, ups, soap-extension, ups-api

[Need Raw XML For Request & Response In UPS API (.Net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365715/need-raw-xml-for-request-response-in-ups-api-net/11640429#11640429)

Trying to implement logging with code posted from the post above but I am having trouble with code posted. TranceExtension returns everything as null. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can someone please lend a hand? Please?

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question. For those who struggle like I did, if you are getting Null for both Request and Respose, need to register the extension before instantiating the ShipService.

TraceExtension.RegisterSoapExtension( typeof( TraceExtension ), 1, 0 );
ShipService shpSvc = new ShipService();

Hope this help someone :)